# How to make clangd to enable header-only library implementation

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, clangd, header-only

There is a way of distributing C/C++ libraries as a one header-only file. Library is in one `library.h` file: header declarations together with implementation hidden under `#ifdef LIBRARY_IMPL`. You need to create some `.c`/`.cpp` file that does `#define LIBRARY_IMPL; #include "library.h"` which creates compilation unit with implementation.

I have a project which uses such libraries extensively. Project build system creates `compile_commands.json` which is then used by `clangd` to provide project paths, data structures and hints to VSCode (with *llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd*).

The issue I have is when opening the `library.h` file for editing, the symbol `LIBRARY_IMPL` is not defined, thus the `#ifdef LIBRARY_IMPL` section is treated as comment - without syntax highlighting, type checking etc.

Is there a way to tell `clangd` or the extension to treat the file as it was during compilation of the `library.c` wrapper file, not stand-alone .h file?

Comment: the `c_cpp_properties.json` has a `defines` property

Comment: Another way for **[header only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only) C++ libraries** is with `template`  and `inline`; **for an example** see [this header only HTTP library](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib)

Comment: Clangd has a project-wide config file where you can specify common compiler flags, maybe you can define your macro there.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What does `make` have to do with anything? You'll still need to generate the same `compiler_commands.json` regardless of build system choice. Regarding `inline`: this is way slower that only having the implementation in a single TU.

Comment: Don’t call this arrangement “header-only”; that term has a specific meaning here.  You could call it something like “implementation conditionally included in the header”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to create a `.clangd` file in your project's root directory, containing:

```yaml
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-DLIBRARY_IMPL]
```

This instructs clangd to add the flag `-DLIBRARY_IMPL` (which has the effect of defining the macro `LIBRARY_IMPL`) to any compile command used when opening a file in your project.

Note, for this to be effective, `library.h` needs to be located in the directory tree of your project (because the `.clangd` file will only apply to files in that directory tree).

If `library.h` is located outside the project directory, an alternative approach would be to create a [user config file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#files) containing the same thing, but this time you probably want to make it conditional on the file's path:

```yaml
If:
  PathMatch: /path/to/library/library.h

CompileFlags:
  Add: [-DLIBRARY_IMPL]
```

You can read more about clangd config files at https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `defines` field of the `c_cpp_properties.json` file to set `#define`s in a way that `clangd` can see. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) is the full schema reference. The relevant portion is

```
"configurations": [
  {
    ...
    "defines": ["FOO", "BAR=100"],
    ...
  },
]
```

This is where you would put your `LIBRARY_IMPL`. Your `c_cpp_properties.json` file should be in the top level directory of your project folder.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is for configuring [Microsoft's C++ plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools), not clangd. Clangd is usually configured using `compile_commands.json`, see https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup for details. You can also use a [clangd config file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html) to customize the configuration in cases where the `compile_commands.json` generated by the build is not suitable by itself.